# Image format of pictures taken with the camera (Android phones)

Tags: android, image, format, png, jpeg

For my app I have to send a mail with a photo (I'm using a webservice to do that).

I'd like to know if there are some Android phones that does not produce jpg file with the camera (such as png file).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think every device *should* support JPEG images, because the description of the

```
takePicture (Camera.ShutterCallback shutter, Camera.PictureCallback raw, Camera.PictureCallback postview, Camera.PictureCallback jpeg)
```

method says that only raw and postview callbacks may be null.

On the other side, you may always call

```
camera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureFormats()
```

to see what picture formats are supported.

Comment: Thank's for your quick answer

Comment: And how do I set that format to the image I am about to take (API 21)